# How to differentiate single tap gesture and double tap gesture?

Tags: ios

I add both single and double tap gestures to one `UIImageView`, then the problem is every time I tried to double tap, it executed single tap's `UITapGestureRecognizer` first.

How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You maybe need requireGestureRecognizerToFail: method. Something like this:

```
[singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
```